# What does えんやらやっと mean?

Tags: words, meaning

I'm trying to learn Japanese.  I'm reading (trying to anyway) a Japanese kid book and found this line:

> あさ
>   いもほり
>   うでまくり
>   **えんやら**やっと
>   おおきな　おいも

I found by Googling that やっと means 'finally'.  But what does えんやら mean?

Comment: Please always post the full sentence for context.

Comment: It would also be great to see any ideas you have about the meaning.

Comment: I found by Googling that やっと means 'finally'

Comment: My sorry attempt at translation produced gibberish "Potato digging in the morning, rolling up sleeves, finally, large potato."  I'm an absolute beginner.  Sorry.

Comment: So is it `えんやら` or `えにゃら`?

Comment: It's えんやら, but looking that up on Google says that ん can be used as an abbreviation for  に or の.  Is that so?

Comment: @istrasci Oh, sorry, I see what you mean now.  I used a Romaji-to-Hiragana converter and I guess it changed that automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably えんやらやっと (spelled using a small っ in modern Japanese), and to me it sounds like one of the various words people say when physically exerting themselves, e.g. lifting something heavy. Like a big potato.

Think よいしょっと.

Edit: According to [this Google result](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%88%E3%82%93%E3%82%84%E3%82%89-448268) that is exactly what it is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer.  Like I said I'm a newbie so I probably wouldn't have figured this out.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this one. I know えんやこら, which seems related.